# OpenCV mat to SFML image

Tags: c++, opencv, sfml

Is there a way to format an OpenCV mat to a SFML image. Or is there any other way to display the mat in a SFML window?
I've tried converting the mat array into a uchar array, but the result is a black screen.

```
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video file for reading
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Image image;
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    cv::Mat frame;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 900),"my Window");
    cap >> frame;
    uchar* camData = new uchar[frame.total()*4];
    cv::Mat continuousRGBA(frame.size(), CV_8UC4, camData);
    cv::cvtColor(frame, continuousRGBA, CV_BGR2RGBA, 4);
    image.create(frame.cols,frame.rows,camData);
    texture.loadFromImage(image);
    while (window.isOpen()){
        cap >> frame;
        cv::cvtColor(frame, continuousRGBA, CV_BGR2RGBA, 4);
        image.create(frame.cols,frame.rows,camData);
        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works me fine:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video file for reading
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    return 0;
}

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 900), "RenderWindow");
cv::Mat frameRGB, frameRGBA;
sf::Image image;
sf::Texture texture;
sf::Event event;
sf::Sprite sprite;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    cap >> frameRGB;

    if(frameRGB.empty())
    {
        break;
    }

    cv::cvtColor(frameRGB, frameRGBA, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

    image.create(frameRGBA.cols, frameRGBA.rows, frameRGBA.ptr());

    if (!texture.loadFromImage(image))
    {
        break;
    }

    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
}
```

There was a problem with managing `camData`. You allocate memory outside from the loop, but `cv::cvtColor()` will reassign `continuousRGBA` over and over, that's why you see a black screen.